# Difference in usage between “похоже” and “вроде”

Tags: словоупотребление

When used in a phrase such as "похоже на" and "вроде меня", "похоже" and "вроде" are not interchangeable. But how are they nuanced in the following instances?

> Холод, **похоже**, ее совершенно не беспокоит.
>
> Они **вроде** обычно не особо дружелюбны к чужим.

And how does "вроде бы" compare?

> Они **вроде бы** чувствуют себя вполне комфортно.

Comment: Interestingly, "вроде бы" does not require a verb in the past tense, despite the presence of "бы".

Comment: it's because it doesn't turn the mood of a sentence into conditional, compare **как бы, будто бы, якобы**

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens that's because it is a parenthesis, not a verb.

Answer (score 2):

`вроде` is more informal but they're otherwise identical. Both mean that you do uneducated guess about other person's inner state.

`вроде бы` is no different and could be substituted too:

> Они, похоже, чувствуют себя вполне комфортно.

It only adds one extra tiny mark of uncertainty.